# Verifying mocked object method calls with default arguments

Tags: scala, mockito, default-arguments

Suppose I have this class:

```
class Defaults {
  def doSomething(regular: String, default: Option[String] = None) = {
    println(s"Doing something: $regular, $default")
  }
}
```

I want to check that some other class invokes `doSomething()` method on `Defaults` instance without passing second argument:

```
defaults.doSomething("abcd")  // second argument is None implicitly
```

However, mocking `Defaults` class does not work correctly. Because default values for method arguments are compiled as hidden methods in the same class, `mock[Defaults]` returns an object in which these hidden methods return `null` instead of `None`, so this test fails:

```
class Test extends FreeSpec with ShouldMatchers with MockitoSugar {
  "Defaults" - {
    "should be called with default argument" in {
      val d = mock[Defaults]

      d.doSomething("abcd")

      verify(d).doSomething("abcd", None)
    }
  }
}
```

The error:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
defaults.doSomething("abcd", None);
-> at defaults.Test$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(Test.scala:14)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
defaults.doSomething("abcd", null);
-> at defaults.Test$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(Test.scala:12)
```

The reason of this is clear, but is there a sensible workaround? The only one I see is to use `spy()` instead of `mock()`, but my mocked class contains a lot of methods which I will have to mock explicitly in this case, and I don't want it.

Comment: Unfortunately, If you are using argument matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#3

Comment: @JhonnyEverson, I never said I was using matchers. You can see from my examples that there is no single matcher is used.

Comment: ah right, sorry. Maybe you could use some implicit params instead of default params, but I am not sure it would work. Just an idea.

Comment: I am not certain Mockito can do this. In your case `d` is simply a standard Java proxy which internally calls the real instance of ``Defaults``. Since Java has no notion of the Some/None paradigm, it will use null when dynamically binding the arguments - for Java your doSomething() method is an ordinary 2-parameter method, so the reflective call will need to fill the arg list with something, which in your case is `null`. 
BTW, have you tried solving this with the native ScalaMock?

Answer (score 8):

This is related with how the Scala compiler implements this as a Java class, remember that Scala runs on the JVM, so everything needs to be transformed to something that looks like Java

In this particular case, what the compiler does is to create a series of hidden methods which will be called something like *methodName$default$number* where *number* is the position of the argument this method is representing, then, the compiler will check every time we call this method and if we don’t provide a value for such parameter, it will insert a call to the $default$ method in its place, an example of the “compiled” version would be something like this (note that this is not exactly what the compiler does, but it works for educational purposes)

```
class Foo {
   def bar(noDefault: String, default: String = "default value"): String
}
val aMock = mock[Foo]

aMock.bar("I'm not gonna pass the second argument")
```

The last line would be compiled as

```
aMock.bar("I'm not gonna pass the second argument", aMock.bar$default$1)
```

Now, because we are making the call to `bar$default$1` on a mock, and the default behaviour of Mockito is to return `null` for anything that hasn’t been stubbed, then what ends up executing is something like

```
aMock.iHaveSomeDefaultArguments("I'm not gonna pass the second argument", null)
```

Which is exactly what the error is telling…

In order to solve this some changes have to be made so mockito actually calls the real `$default$` methods and so the replacement is done correctly

This work has been done in [mockito-scala](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala), so by migrating to that library you'll get a solution for this and many other problems that can be found when mockito is used in Scala

Disclaimer: I'm a developer of mockito-scala