# Mockito: 0 matchers expected, 1 recorded

Tags: scala, playframework, mockito, scalatest, mockito-scala

I have the folliwng PlaySpec:

```scala
"Service A" must {

   "do the following" in {
       val mockServiceA = mock[ServiceA]
       val mockServiceB = mock[ServiceB]
       when(mockServiceA.applyRewrite(any[ClassA])).thenReturn(resultA) // case A
       when(mockServiceB.execute(any[ClassA])).thenReturn(Future{resultB})

       // test code continuation
   }
}
```

The definition of `ServiveA` and `ServiceB` are

```scala
class ServiceA {
    def applyRewrite(instance: ClassA):ClassA = ???
}

class ServiceB {
   def execute(instance: ClassA, limit: Option[Int] = Some(3)) = ???
}
```

Mocking `ServiceA#applyRewrite` works perfectly.
Mocking `ServiceB#execute` fails with the following exception:

```
Invalid use of argument matchers!
0 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
-> at RandomServiceSpec.$anonfun$new$12(RandomServiceSpec.scala:146)

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));
```

Although the instructions included in the exception seem a bit counterintuitive to me I have tried the following:

```scala
when(mockServiceB.execute(anyObject[ClassA])).thenReturn(Future{resultB})
when(mockServiceB.execute(anyObject())).thenReturn(Future{resultB})
when(mockServiceB.execute(anyObject)).thenReturn(Future{resultB})
when(mockServiceB.execute(any)).thenReturn(Future{resultB})
when(mockServiceB.execute(any, Some(3))).thenReturn(Future{resultB})
when(mockServiceB.execute(any[ClassA], Some(3))).thenReturn(Future{resultB})
```

All unfortunately to no avail. The only thing that changes is the number of expected and recorded matchers the exception refers to.

The weirdest thing for me though is that the mocking works perfectly for **case A**.

Comment: Can you verify that it is working if you do not assign a default value to limit? (using what `@MarioGalic` posted as a comment).

Comment: @second It's not that easy.... I would have to change virtually every invocation in the code base...

Comment: Just use an isolated test (like the one in your question) as an example and test it out. If I understand it correctly the problem might be the internal handling of default values in scala, which refer to some `auto generated` methods that your mock does not cover.

Comment: Refer to this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25115329/verifying-mocked-object-method-calls-with-default-arguments) to get some more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the idiomatic syntax of mockito-scala and all the stuff related to the default argument will be deal with by the framework

```
mockServiceB.execute(*) returns Future.sucessful(resultB)
```

if you add the cats integration it could reduce to just

```
mockServiceB.execute(*) returnsF resultB
```

more info [here](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala#idiomatic-mockito)

Comment: If you use it like this, that is no control to the inputs, and he wants to do a different thing based on the Option[Int]

Comment: In the code snippet he only seem to care about the first parameter... in any case, there is nothing in my examples stopping him to modify the shape and number of marchers to fulfil his requirements

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this:

import org.mockito.ArgumentMatchersSugar._

```
when(mockServiceB.execute(any[ClassA], eqTo(Some(3)))).thenReturn(Future{resultB})
```

When you use any and the function receives multiple arguments you need to pass the other arguments that are not any with eq(something), hope this helps.

EDITED: My bad forgot the import and is eqTo and not eq

Comment: This does not even compile. The error is `expected Option[Int] but found Boolean`. The code is exactly the one you attached.

Comment: @Niko Try `ArgumentMatchers.eq(Some(3))`, or `any[Option[Int]]`.

Comment: @MarioGalic It's still not working. The error changed to `Invalid use of argument matchers!
3 matchers expected, 2 recorded:
-> at RandomServiceSpec.$anonfun$new$12(RandomServiceSpec.scala:147)
-> at RandomServiceSpec.$anonfun$new$12(RandomServiceSpec.scala:147)`